# Issue with drawing of controls as part of Load/Shown event

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, drawing, controls

So I have a Windows Form application that is having some strange issues.

I notice that when some forms are shown they will show white boxes where all of the controls are instead of the text.

Here are some [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnrVA.jpg) of the problem.

I originally had everything in the Load event and moved to the shown event.  It still had problem so I moved the actual work part into a different method and added a delegate to write new files to the checkedlistbox control in case that was the issue.

Unfortunately it still happens and I'm confused.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub form_FileCleanup_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    frmMain.Hide()
    Me.BringToFront()
    DoWork()
End Sub

Private Sub DoWork()

    For Each _file As KeyValuePair(Of String, FileInfoList.fileInfoS) In fl.FileRemoveList
        Dim fi As FileInfoList.fileInfoS = _file.Value
        UpdateFileListl(fi.FullName)
        'cbxFileList.Items.Add(fi.FullName, False)
    Next

    lblStatusMessage.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Delegate Sub FileListUpdateDelegate(fileName As String)
Private Sub UpdateFileListl(fileName As String)
    Try
        If Me.cbxFileList.InvokeRequired Then
            cbxFileList.Invoke(New FileListUpdateDelegate(AddressOf UpdateFileListl), fileName)
        Else
            cbxFileList.Items.Add(fileName, False)
            cbxFileList.Update()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLogs.Add(ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Upload the image in stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like it is busy doing something else and doesnt have time to paint the controls

Comment: Probably your `DoWork` is time-consuning and makes UI tread busy. Use [Async/Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674902.aspx) or use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: I agree but nothing else should be going on, I've moved everything out of the Load and Shown event.

I just commented out DoWork and it still happens.

Comment: Ok you guys got me thinking and I went back to the main form and I see what the problem is.  It's trying to remove empty folders at the same time.  I commented that out and now there are no white boxes.  Thanks for the ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

In the main form it was running a CPU intensive task.  For some reason in my mind I was thinking it would be sequential in nature but the new form was doing work at the same time as the old form which caused the issue.